# PHP - Tweak code containing session and redirect

Tags: php, html

I am having a LAMP Server on my Raspberry Pi. I have a static page to control my home switches. Also, I have a button which load the following php code.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
   # Session Close
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION['valid']);
   unset($_SESSION['timeout']);
   
   # Server Shutdown
   system('sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now');
   
   # Redirect Page
   header("refresh:0.1;url=https://www.google.com");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- container -->
   </body>
</html>
```

The above code is doing: `close session`, `shutdown server` and `redirect to a page`.

This code seems to work fine but with delay... It takes time to load page. Press button and waiting...

I would like to ask if i can have the same result `but faster`. I need a tweak / speed up... Press button and instantly load redirect page and at the same time do the rest.

Comment: Change your `header()` call to do a proper redirect `header("Location: https://www.google.com/");`. Delete everything after it, including `?>` and replace it with `session_write_close(); die();`

Comment: @miken32 Can you please give an answer below as i am missing something, pls. Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: See answers to the duplicate question